# Errors in handling smart pointers

Tags: c++, polymorphism, smart-pointers

I am struggling to understand how smart pointers work. I have to solve a practice exercise, where I am supposed to write three classes: a 'Base' class and two derivative class 'File' and 'Directory', in order to simulate a file system. The 'Base' class is an abstract class with a string.

I've written all the methods I want to use, expect the ls() method that I just filled with a simple print, and tried to run a simple program but the compiler returns errors that I am not able to understand.

I started working on smart pointer recently so I am probably doing something wrong handling them.

Here is my UDT.h

```c
#ifndef UDT_H
#define UDT_H

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <memory>

class Base {
    private:
        std::string name;

    public:
        std::string getName() const;                // --> returns name

        explicit Base(std::string name): name(name){};
        virtual int mType () const = 0;             // returns 1 if Dir and 2 if File
        virtual void ls (int indent) const = 0;
};

class File: public Base{
    private:
        uintmax_t sizeFile;

    public:
        int mType () const override{return 2;};

        File(std::string name, uintmax_t size);     // --> class file constructor

        uintmax_t getSize () const;
        void ls (int indent = 0) const override;    // --> print the name of the file with the correct indentation
};

class Directory: public Base{                       // implemented with private constructor in order to have just one root
    public:
        int mType () const override{return 1;};

        static std::shared_ptr<Directory> getRoot();                // --> returns the shared pointer to the root
        std::shared_ptr<Directory> addDirectory(std::string name);  // --> adds one sub directory
        std::shared_ptr<File> addFile(std::string name, uintmax_t size);    // adds one file to the directory

        std::shared_ptr<Base> get (std::string name);               // --> returns shared pointer to the file/dir with name == name
        std::shared_ptr<Directory> getDir (std::string name);       // --> returns shared pointer to the file/dir with name == name
        std::shared_ptr<File> getFile (std::string name);           // --> returns shared pointer to the file/dir with name == name

        void remove (std::string name);
        void ls (int indent = 0) const override;                    // --> print the content of the dir with the correct indentation

    private:
        std::weak_ptr<Directory> myself;                            // --> weak pointer to itself
        std::weak_ptr<Directory> parent;                            // --> weak pointer to parent
        static std::shared_ptr<Directory> root;                     // --> shared pointer to root
        std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Base>> list;                    // --> list of dir/file(s) in the directory
        explicit Directory(std::string name, std::shared_ptr<Directory> parent);    // --> dir constructor
};



#endif //UDT_H
```

Here is the UDT.cpp

```c
#include "UDT.h"

std::shared_ptr<Directory> Directory::root;

std::string Base::getName() const {
    return this->name;
}

Directory::Directory(std::string name, std::shared_ptr<Directory> parent): Base(name) {
    this->parent = parent;
    this->myself = std::shared_ptr<Directory>(this);
}

File::File(std::string name, uintmax_t size):Base(std::move(name)) {
    sizeFile = size;
}

std::shared_ptr<Directory> Directory::getRoot() {
    if (root == nullptr){ // --> create root directory if not already created
        root = std::shared_ptr<Directory>(new Directory("/", nullptr));
    }
    return root;
}

std::shared_ptr<Directory> Directory::addDirectory(std::string name) {
    if (name == "." || name == "..")
        throw std::exception();

    for(int i = 0 ; i < list.size() ; i++){
        if(list[i]->getName() == name)
            throw std::exception(); // object with the same name --> throw exception
    }

    // if no object with the same name --> add it!

    std::shared_ptr<Directory> newDir = std::shared_ptr<Directory>(new Directory(name, this->myself.lock()));
    return newDir;
}

std::shared_ptr<File> Directory::addFile(std::string name, uintmax_t size) {
    if (name == "." || name == "..")
        throw std::exception();

    for(int i = 0 ; i < list.size() ; i++){
        if(list[i]->getName() == name)
            throw std::exception(); // object with the same name --> throw exception
    }

    // if no object with the same name --> add it!
    std::shared_ptr<File> newFile = std::make_shared<File>(name, size);
    return newFile;
}

std::shared_ptr<Base> Directory::get(std::string name) {
    if (name == "." )
        return std::shared_ptr<Base>(this->myself);

    if (name == ".." )
        return std::shared_ptr<Base>(this->parent);

    for(int i = 0 ; i < list.size() ; i++){
        if(list[i]->getName() == name)
            return list[i];
    }

    return nullptr;
}

std::shared_ptr<Directory> Directory::getDir(std::string name) {
    if (name == "." )
        return this->myself.lock();

    if (name == ".." )
        return this->parent.lock();

    for(int i = 0 ; i < list.size() ; i++){
        if(list[i]->getName() == name)
            return std::dynamic_pointer_cast<Directory>(list[i]);
    }

    return nullptr;
}

std::shared_ptr<File> Directory::getFile(std::string name) {
    if (name == "." || name == ".." )
        return nullptr;

    for(int i = 0 ; i < list.size() ; i++){
        if(list[i]->getName() == name)
            return std::dynamic_pointer_cast<File>(list[i]);
    }

    return nullptr;
}

void Directory::remove(std::string name) {
    if (name == "." || name == "..")
        throw std::exception();

    for(int i = 0; i < list.size() ; i++){
        if (list[i]->getName() == name){
            list.erase(list.begin() + i);
        }
    }
}

uintmax_t File::getSize() const {
    return sizeFile;
}

void Directory::ls(int indent) const {
    std::cout << "ls" << std::endl;
}

void File::ls(int indent) const {
    std::cout << "ls" << std::endl;
}
```

And the main.cpp

```c
#include <iostream>
#include "UDT.h"

int main() {

    std::shared_ptr <Directory> root = Directory::getRoot();
    auto alfa = root -> addDirectory( "alfa");
    alfa -> addDirectory("beta") -> addFile( "beta1", 100);
    alfa -> getDir("beta") -> addFile( "beta2", 200);
    alfa -> getDir("..") -> ls();
    alfa -> remove("beta");
    root -> ls();

    return 0;
}
```

I get this error:
`(5486,0x114c015c0) malloc: *** error for object 0x6000000000000000: pointer being freed was not allocated`
`(5486,0x114c015c0) malloc: *** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug`

Please help me understand what's the problem

Comment: `std::shared_ptr<Directory>(this)` is immediately and very suspicious. For example, in `this->myself = std::shared_ptr<Directory>(this);` you are getting a `weak_ptr` to a *different* smart pointer (one you make on the spot) from the one that actually owns the instance. One consequence is that once you've gotten your `weak_ptr`, the associated `shared_ptr` will be destroyed at the end of the expression causing `this` to be destroyed, before it even finished it's own construction. Edit : You probably want to use `std::enable_shared_from_this` instead of having a `myself` member.

Comment: "I am struggling to understand how smart pointers work"  - they really are simple. They keep the object alive as long as any smart poiner refering to the object is alive. When the last smart pointer refering to the object is destroyed, the object itself is destroyed.

Comment: Note that there is no way to know, during the constructor, whether or not an object will be owned by a `shared_ptr`, much less know which one will owns it. It's not possible to capture a `weak_ptr` that will point to `this` from within the constructor. You need the collaboration of the smart pointer to notify your type, but you can't implement that yourself if you are using the standard smart pointers. That why [`std::enable_shared_from_this`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/enable_shared_from_this) exists. `std::shared_ptr` knows to notify such objects.

Comment: Looking through this here you have odd ownership semantics. In almost every case where you use a shared pointer for ownership you could have used a unique_ptr instead. In all cases where you used a shared_ptr or weak_ptr to provide access you could have used a raw pointer or reference. In fact you might not ever need pointers at all for ownership. If you construct the root at the beginning and every directory goes in a vector of Directory and File objects what do you need pointers for?

Comment: You might be better able to understand the problem if you were to create a [mcve], with emphasis on "minimal".  Do you need all of those lines in your main function? Take out what you can while still keeping the error. Then strip down your class implementation.

Comment: Ok I found out that the error comes from the first line of the main `std::shared_ptr <Directory> root = Directory::getRoot();` and when the program tries to perform the code `if...root = std::shared_ptr<Directory>(new Directory("/", nullptr));...` it calls the constructor of Directory that calls the Base constructor. Everything's fine BUT immediately after this line `this->myself = std::shared_ptr<Directory>(this);` at the end of the block the debugger makes two steps on the `}` and in the variables section it displays the error: `parent failed to evaluate: variable not available`